# Strongly named / signed Berkelium-Sharp assembly

Tags: chromium, strongname, assembly-signing, berkelium

I need to use Berkelium-Sharp from signed code.  Does anyone know where I could download a strongly named assembly?

Is there anyone reading this that is currently compiling Berkelium-Sharp successfully and could compile a strongly named dll for me.

I know that I could do it myself, but compiling it appears to require the full Chomium source code, and I'm not sure if I would then need to compile that all as well, and Berkelium itself.  It is a thread that I'd rather not pulling on as I could see days unraveling.

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The berkelium-sharp build instructions explain that you can use a pre-built binary Berkelium SDK: http://code.google.com/p/berkelium-sharp/source/browse/trunk/BUILDING.txt . So you shouldn't need to build all of Chromium, or even build Berkelium. You should just need to modify the berkelium-sharp Visual Studio project to generate a strongly-named assembly (provide the appropriate signing settings, e.g. private key) and build berkelium-sharp. This works because berkelium-sharp just provides managed classes that wrap/replace the native C++ classes and can interact with the native versions.